# Cómo hacer un if not exits con un join en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando la base de datos para una barbería donde se tiene que sacar la cita con el barbero y se debe seleccionar la fecha y hora. Por lo tanto estoy creando un storage procedure donde se guarde la información en la tabla **citas** pero antes quiero validar que no exista ya una cita agendada con ese barbero a esa hora. La forma en que lo estoy haciendo es con un if not exists pero no sé como implementarle el join ya que se tienen que unir las tablas de **trabajadores** con **citas**, esta es mi tabla de trabajador.

```
CREATE TABLE TRABAJADOR(
ID_TRABAJADOR INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
NUM_TEL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TRABAJADOR
PRIMARY KEY (ID_TRABAJADOR)
);
```

Esta es mi tabla de servicios

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICIOS(
ID_SERV INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
MONTO DOUBLE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_SERVICIOS
PRIMARY KEY (ID_SERV)
);
```

Esta es la tabla de citas

```
CREATE TABLE CITAS(
ID_CITA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
HORA TIME NOT NULL,
ID_SERV_FK INT NOT NULL,
ID_USR_FK INT NOT NULL,
ID_TRAB_FK INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_CITA
PRIMARY KEY(ID_CITA),
CONSTRAINT FK_CITA_USUARIO
FOREIGN KEY(ID_USR_FK)
REFERENCES USUARIO(ID_USR),
CONSTRAINT FK_CITA_TRABAJADOR
FOREIGN KEY(ID_TRAB_FK)
REFERENCES TRABAJADOR(ID_TRABAJADOR),
CONSTRAINT FK_CITA_SERVICIO
FOREIGN KEY(ID_SERV_FK)
REFERENCES SERVICIOS(ID_SERV)
);
```

Y este es el procedure de insertar citas

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CITAS_INSERT(
ID_USR_FK_PR INT,
ID_TRAB_FK_PR INT,
ID_SERV_FK_PR INT,
FECHA_PR DATE,
HORA_PR TIME
)
BEGIN 
    IF( NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CITAS WHERE FECHA =  FECHA_PR AND HORA = HORA_PR)) THEN
        INSERT INTO CITAS(ID_USR_FK, ID_TRAB_FK, ID_SERV_FK, FECHA, HORA) VALUES (ID_USR_FK_PR, ID_TRAB_FK_PR, ID_SERV_FK_PR, FECHA_PR, HORA_PR);
    END IF;
END //
```

Lo datos que tengo que validar son que si hay una cita programada con un barbero a una hora y día en específico entonces que no se permita el ingreso de los datos. Y si el espacio está libre entonces que si ingresen los datos.

Comment: Cuál es el problema exactamente? Por lo que veo uno de los parámetros que pasan al SP es el id del trabajador y del servicio, ya con eso estaría la validación.

Comment: El problema es que si lo valido así como lo puse solo valida que no haya una cita en ese horario pero en la barbería hay más barberos por lo que debo validar que no haya una cita en ese horario del barbero seleccionado

Comment: Bueno, es muy simple, tu tabla citas tiene una FK `ID_TRAB_FK` entonces solo bastaría con agregarle otra condición `AND` igualándolo al parámetro que pasan en el SP. Algo así: `AND ID_TRAB_FK = ID_TRAB_FK_PR `

Comment: Te agradezco mucho! Lo intentaré y te aviso!!!

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!